# Joomla different column width for different pages

Tags: layout, joomla, width, multiple-columns

I'm using Joomla 3.4 and Bootstrap in it. I have basic layout which contain main content on the left side and right sidebar on the right. Main content is 75% width of the container (col-sm-9) and right sidebar is 25% (col-sm-3). This is fine for all pages except one that main content should be only 66.66% (col-sm-8) width of container and right sidebar 33.33% (col-sm-4). How can I do that? I don't want to duplicate or use other templates.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

on approach is, on specific page
1)with jQuery you can chage class from col-sm-9 to col-sm-8
or
2)you can overide css rule .col-sm-9 & col-sm-3 & set width to 66% or whatever.

e.g your specific page is index.php?option=com_mycom&view=myview then inside components/mycom/views/myview/tmpl/default.php you will be adding

```
#content
{
    width:66.66%;
}
#aside
{
    width:33.30%;
}
```

where #content is id of main content & #aside is id of right column

Comment: Yes, but how to for example add custom CSS class to HTML or BODY tag? I can add custom styles for component but not the BODY or HTML.

Comment: I found this solution but it is not what I want. Set the active slug name `<?php $active = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu()->getActive(); ?>` and append it as css class to body tag `<body class="<?php echo $active->alias; ?>">`. It will be better to have class for example like `<body class="wide-sidebar">`

Comment: Another solution is to edit the link in the menu item - just append to the end `?tmpl=name-of-template` or `&tmpl=name-of-template` depends on the menu item link. And then create the 'name-of-template.php' file in the template root. But this is still not good solution because if the menu item will be changed and then set back, it will loose this URL parameter and the default template will be used.